# How would you model a read/follow systems?

Tags: oop, model, domain-driven-design

So I've the following domain model :

`Article` which is basically a blog post and currently an Entity.

Now, I'd like to add the following feature :

- When an user view the article (in its browser), an api call is made to "flag" the blog post as being read.

> Now, if I do some computation, I should be able to determine which articles haven't been read yet.

- When an user post a comment to an article, an api call is made to "flag" the blog post as being followed.

> Now, if I do some computation, I should be able to determine if there are some new posted comments since the latest user's comment post.

Basically, both feature (read & follow) share the attribute, an article id, an user id and a read/action date.

Note that, if an Article is followed, and then read, the read date should be used.

Therefore, I though I could use the same object and adding an extra attributes to mark it as followed.

Do you have any design ideas?

Note that are much articles & users, I'm using Doctrine2 and MySQL but this apply to any languages.

Answer (score 1):

To ensure your application scales well, I'd do your computations locally when the events are triggered.  I.e. someone adds a comment and it causes the system to check who has an investment in that new comment.  Otherwise you end up with a scheduled task processing all the data, which will run fine at first, but will have an exponentially increasing workload as the relations between users, articles and comments increases.

You can also look into using the Map/Reduce pattern, [Ayende](http://ayende.com/blog/4435/map-reduce-a-visual-explanation) has a good introduction article to this, which is almost in the same application domain as you describe (articles, comments, etc.).

As for the event of marking an article or comment as read by a particular user, this is something that is neither an article or user thing.  If you were using a document database and wanted to store this data against a user, then it could build up quite a bit of data over time, I'd be more tempted to either store the data in a new entity or against the article (as in theory this will have an initial burst of interest and them dip in interest to a level representing it's popularity.

Hopefully some of that might help.